Enable keyboard as mouse when trackpad is not responsive
I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I have no internet access, and my trackpad is not controlling the cursor. There are instructions for enabling keyboard control of the cursor, but they only work if one already has a working mouse/trackpad. How do I turn on keyboard-based cursor control via the terminal?
EDIT: I've managed to get to the setting for it in Settings using only keyboard controls, but pressing the space bar does't toggle it.
